# how can I group rows from a DataFrame into a single row separated by a delimiter Scala Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this DataFrame of Spark:

```
+-------------+
|father|child |
+-------------+
|Aaron |Adam  |
|Aaron |Berel |
|Aaron |Kasper|
|Levi  |Saul  |
|Levi  |Tiger |
+-------------+
```

How can I group by parents and put all the data together in a single field with delimiter?

My desired output would be:

```
+------------------------+
|union_all_name_by_father|
+------------------------+
|Aaron;Adam;Berel;Kasper |
|Levi;Saul;Tiger         |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: In Scala, I haven't tried anything, I don't know which way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and then `concat_ws`:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("father").agg(
    concat_ws(";", collect_list(col("child"))).as("col2")
).select(concat_ws(";", col("father"), col("col2")).as("union_all_name_by_father"))

df2.show(false)
+------------------------+
|union_all_name_by_father|
+------------------------+
|Aaron;Adam;Berel;Kasper |
|Levi;Saul;Tiger         |
+------------------------+
```